# The "text-align: center" isn't working in a span element

Tags: html, text-align

I haven't done HTML and CSS for a while so I may be forgetting something, but for some reason a "style" tag with the "text-align" property set isn't working even in the simplest context. I'm about to show you the whole, entire file that I have but my problem is only in the two comments I have. Don't worry about the other stuff; it's for a little passion project I'm working on.

So here is the whole file. I have a lot of stuff in it that isn't relevant nor important; just focus on the code in the two comments.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>JSON Generator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="web_mod.css"></link>
</head>
<body bgColor="#E3E3E3">
<!--Start here-->
<span style="text-align: center">Coded by AnnualMelons</span><br>
<!--Finish here-->
<span style="color: red; background-color: #2CE65A">Use this generator to generate the code required to create a JSON message.<br>
Fill in the blanks to generate the code. The generator will guide you through it as you go along. Have fun!</span>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The "Coded by AnnualMelons" part is supposed to be in the center but it's not. At least for me it's not.

I know that the other part of the file isn't relevant but I figured I might as well show you as it may be an external problem.

I'm sure I'm just making a silly mistake because I haven't done this for a while, but it's not working... so yeah. I'm using Firefox as my web browser in case that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `<span>` Element is, by default, an ["inline" element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente). Meaning unlike [block level elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) (`<div>` `<h1>` `<p>` etc.) the span only takes up **as much horizontal space as its content.**

`text-align: center` IS working, but you're applying it to an element that doesn't have a width greater than its content (as all block elements do).

I recommend either changing the span to a `<p>` element, or specifying the `display: block` property on your span.

[Here's a JSfiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/Morklympious/p9nnofg8/) that both a `<span>` with `display: block; text-align: center` and a `<p>` with `text-align: center;` achieve the same effect.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

Use a p or div rather than a span. Text is an inline element and so is a span. For text-align to work, it must be used on a block level element (p, div, etc.) to center the inline content.

example:

```
<div style="text-align: center">Coded by AnnualMelons</div><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this in style

```
margin-left: 50%;
```

example-

```
   <span style="margin-left: 45%;">Centered Text</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.span { 
       text-align: center;
       width: -webkit-fill-available;
      }
```

This Worked for me and the text inside my span tag is now aligned to the center.