# Centering Text in a Span tag not working as required

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
    const spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");
    const animation = function () {
      for (let span of spans) span.classList.toggle("fade");
    };
    //setInterval(animation, 2400);
```

```css
.animated {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #d1d8e0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.animated span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.animated>.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .animated {
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animated">
   Hey, I'm<br>
   <span class="color-primary fade" id="animated-name">Name Name</span>
   <span class="color-primary" id="animated-text">Description about something <br>Text & Text</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to align text to the center of the page and to be responsive for all devices.

I have tried several option but none of them worked:

Trial No.1:
added `style="margin:auto;` in the span

Trial No.2:
added `style="margin-left:-188;` in the span

Trial No.3:
added `style="text-align: center;"` in the div before the span

Trial No.4
added `position: absolute;` in the animated span

In the home.html

```
<div class="animated">
   Hey, I'm<br>
   <span class="color-primary fade" id="animated-name">Name Name</span>
   <span class="color-primary" id="animated-text">Description about something</br>Text & 
    Text</span>
</div>
```

In the css

```
.animated {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #d1d8e0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.animated span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.animated>.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .animated {
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}
```

In the base.html

```
    <script>
    const spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");
    const animation = function () {
      for (let span of spans) span.classList.toggle("fade");
    };
    setInterval(animation, 2400);
    </script>
```

My question is how to cetner the text in the span and when there are long sentences similar to the second span to be also centered

Comment: Replace span with div. Span is an inline element. It has no width or height.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML span align center not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392211/html-span-align-center-not-working) Also see ["text-align: center" isn't working in a span element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477765/the-text-align-center-isnt-working-in-a-span-element) and [align text of span in the center of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039792/align-text-of-span-in-the-center-of-the-page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to leave your span as is, set it to the following:

```
.animated span {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: grid` to achieve that.

Change your `span` elements to `div` (you probably should give those a class to make the CSS clearer)

`grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;` for both of those `div` ensures that they both overlap.
`margin: auto;` ensures that they are centered. And `text-align: center;` that the text itself is centered.

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll(".grid > div");
const animation = function() {
  for (let span of spans) span.classList.toggle("fade");
};
setInterval(animation, 2400);
```

```css
.animated {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #d1d8e0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.animated .grid div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.animated .grid .fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .animated {
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.grid>div {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated">
  Hey, I'm<br>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="color-primary fade" id="animated-name">
       Name Name
    </div>
    <div class="color-primary" id="animated-text">
       Description about something<br>Text &amp; Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

start with placing text-align:center on the div.  Not really clear exactly how you want to display

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");
    const animation = function () {
      for (let span of spans) span.classList.toggle("fade");
    };
    setInterval(animation, 2400);
```

```css
.animated {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #d1d8e0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align:center;
}

.animated span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.animated>.fade {
  opacity: 0;
 
}


@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .animated {
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animated">
   Hey, I'm<br>
   <span class="color-primary fade" id="animated-name">Name Name</span>
   <span class="color-primary" id="animated-text">Description about something <br>Text & Text</span>
</div>
```